# Why can I no longer connect to SQL Server from another PC on my local network?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, sql-server

Why has a SQL Server client stopped connecting to SQL Server running on another node on my local network?

This has been working correctly for a long time. The client PC (PC A) was connecting two days ago. Nothing has been changed on either PC A or the PC hosting SQL Server (MYSERVER). When I try to connect I get the error "Network related error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible." I can connect successfully to the same SQL Server instance from another PC, PC B.

Both PCs are using the same connection string in a C# program, but I have confirmed that a connection from SQL Server Management Studio on PC A also fails. Also the connection in SQL Server Management Studio works if I change the server name to the ip address of the server node i.e. 192.168.178.20\SQLEXPRESS connects, but MYSERVER\SQLEXPRESS fails to connect. It seems that Windows or SQL Client is failing to resolve the host name (though it did so until a couple of days ago).

The two client PCs and the Server PC are running Windows 10. The local network is a workgroup, not a domain. The two clients are using Windows Authentication to connect to the server.

On PC A, I checked

- the HOSTS file does not contain any addresses
- I can ping MYSERVER and it resolves to the correct address 192.168.178.20
- there are no SQL Aliases
- the PC uses the correct DNS server on the router

As a workaround, I have included MYSERVER in the hosts file and I have changed MYSERVER's ip address to a static address 192.168.178.20, but I don't want this permanently.

Any suggestions why the server name is not being resolved or what I could do to investigate further?

Comment: did you try telnet? also check for MSSQL network configuration

Comment: I don't have telnet installed. Does it give more information than verifying connectivity from SSMS?
Also the network configuration hasn't changed, and the other PC can connect successfully using the same connection string as the client that can't connect - is there anything I should look for that might be specific to one client but not the other?

Comment: `telnet sqlserverip 1433`, from every PC you are trying, if it works, fine, if it does not, you need to open this port on the sql server firewall.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was simple. I rebooted my router.

I fixed this with the aid of [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). I compared the packets between the client PC and the server, both when the server's address was in the client's Windows HOSTS file (when the connection to SQL Server always worked), and when the HOSTS file was empty (when the client PC never connected). In both cases I could see TCP packets being exchanged, but with the server address in the hosts file, there were TLS packets as well for the encrypted connection. In the other case, the client appeared to send the connection request to the server but there was no TLS encrypted data.

There may have been some DNS problem in the router. A ping from client to server worked, but there was a slight delay. Although the client was able to resolve the server address from the router to send the TCP packets successfully, I think there may have been a delay when attempting to do the Windows authentication, and that this resulted in the client not sending the authentication request correctly.

Anyway, rebooting the router cleared whatever DNS problem there was, and the client now connects without needing the server's address in the Windows HOSTS file.